# Connection to Azure SQL Database

Tags: aws-glue

I'm have a connection to an Azure SQL Database but the connection test fails.  I've tried all variations of the JDBC connection string, verified the firewall on the Azure side is good.

Get this error when testing the connection... 
Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Full SSL connection to data store using host matching failed.
Exiting with error code 30

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?